# Issue with Displaying Video-Containing Pages in Google Search Results

Tags: seo

I'm facing a peculiar issue with the SEO of my website, and I hope someone can help me out. Pages that contain videos are properly indexed but not displayed in search results. However, pages without videos are indexed well and appear in search results.

My site is built using the Laravel framework. Has anyone encountered a similar issue? What solutions do you suggest for improving the display of pages with videos in Google search results?

Since I encountered this problem, I've tried to investigate various aspects, but I haven't found a definitive solution yet. Any guidance and suggestions you can provide would be helpful.

Thanks to everyone for any assistance.

What solutions do you suggest for improving the display of pages with videos in Google?

Comment: The same SEO rules apply for the video and non-video pages. The signals you are sending will determine how well it ranks in search. The only difference is the actual video itself and how that is impacting the page (performance, page experience, ect.).  Are you leveraging any structured data/schema associated with the video? How are you presenting the video (Youtube embed vs. native player)?

Comment: My video display only in My website ahangvideo.com     Not showed in youtube,...

Answer (score 1):

Since you are hosting your videos directly on your site, I would do the following:

- Add the necessary video related structured data to the page. You can look at [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/video) on the matter as well as [schema.org](https://schema.org/VideoObject).
- Look at the rest of the signals of the page and target keywords in those places. Use the same strategy as you would on non-video pages. Optimize your meta elements as well as any content on the pages themselves.
- If the pages only contain the video itself and no other content, think about adding some additional supplemental content to target those specific keywords.
- Since you aren't leveraging a video embedding service, you might need to look at making videos accessible. This would include providing transcripts of the video. If you go this route, make sure Google can crawl them (either an on-page transcript or a linked file). This will help in the targeting of keywords.
- Look at the performance of the page. What is the end user experience like? How long does it take to load the page? What are your Core Web Vitals? Try to improve the performance to better the end-user experience.